# Create a dictionary with value from an Array

Tags: vba, dictionary

I am working on a report and trying to output my data like this
Input:

[image: Input]

Output

[image: Output]

I am thinking of using a dictionary with each key has multiple value of Items&their but i don't know how to implement.

Comment: Your output cannot be represented using Key/Value pairs because "John" doesn't have a value. And "Checked." is not unique.

Comment: Here's how you can create a `Dictionary` object in VBA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object (you can also use `Dim d`, `Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary`.

Comment: You can use the name for the key and a 2D array of fruit/count for each of the values.  A dictionary is not needed here though - you can just loop over the rows and create the output directly.

Comment: It might help to use Power Query, unpivot the input and then create the output with a pivot based on the transformed input.

Comment: I am sorry if it is not clear. But my point is building a dictionary that has "John", "Mary" as key.
Key "John" has multiple values such as Apple 2, Orange 4, etc and "Checked" value at the end. 
Then i output the dictionary onto the sheet. 
If you have a better way, tell me please.
Thank you.

Comment: So, if you bulit a dictionary as you wrote then you should add the code to the post and tell where you have a problem. And why do you need a `Checked` at the end. Do you need that only in the output? In my opinion it does not make any sense to always add `Checked` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary would not work for your chart example. A dictionary is used to hold ONLY TWO string values using a hashtable. An example of using a dictionary properly is using the two words "hello" and "a polite greeting to another human". The first string is for the word and the second is the definition of the word, just like a regular dictionary.

I would provide you with two better options. You could create a 2D array which holds all your values, but you would need to output the labels separately from the values. You could also create a file which holds the labels and the values for your chart.

If you need more help, please provide more information on what you are trying to do with the chart displayed. An array is better for calculations but a file is better for storing the values and displaying the chart.

Comment: "A dictionary is used to hold ONLY TWO string values using a hashtable"  - this is not true, at least in VBA.  The key is a string, but the value can be anything you care to add.

Comment: so are you saying its not true because the value can hold something other than a string, or that a dictionary can hold more than one value for a key?

Comment: @mry_02: Look at my answer _Second answer_ . That might clarify what Tim Williams said.

Comment: Yes, that the value does not need to be a string, and while it cannot be multiple things, it can be an (eg) array or collection of multiple things

Answer (score 0):

**First answer** as said in one of my comments you could use Power Query to unpivot the data. As example data I took data like this

[image]

After unpivoting the data with PowerQuery (goto *Data* then From Table/Range, select the columns with Apple, Orange etc. in the Power Query Editor, select the tab *Transform* and there *Unpivot columns*) one gets

[image]

Then you pivot the data again and you get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Second answer** would be to use a dictionary of dictionaries. Again input data is
[image]

With the following code

```
Sub DemoDictOfDict()

    Dim rg As Range, rgHdr As Range
    
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim sngDict As Dictionary
    
    Dim wkb As Workbook, wks As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.ActiveSheet
    
    Set rg = wks.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Retrieving the header line from the data
    Set rgHdr = rg.Rows(1).Offset(, 1).Resize(, rg.Columns.Count - 1)
    
    Dim vHdr As Variant
    vHdr = rgHdr.Value
    
    Dim sngRow As Range
    Dim sngCell As Range
    Dim vdat  As Variant
    Dim k As Long
    
    ' Creating the dictionary which will be used
    ' to hold the dictionaries with the data
    Set dict = New Dictionary
    
    ' Looping through the rows of the data
    ' as we are not using the listobject one has to use offset and resizte
    For Each sngRow In rg.Offset(1).Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Rows
    
        ' getting the number for different columns
        ' again listobject not used, so working with resizte and offset
        vdat = sngRow.Offset(, 1).Resize(, sngRow.Columns.Count - 1)
        
        ' Creating the dictionary containing the numbers
        Set sngDict = New Dictionary
            
        For k = LBound(vHdr, 2) To UBound(vHdr, 2)
            ' Adding the values to the "inner" dictionary
            sngDict.Add vHdr(1, k), vdat(1, k)
        Next k
        
        ' Adding the dictionary to the dictionary
        Set dict(sngRow.Cells(1, 1).Value) = sngDict
    Next

    
    ' output to immediate windows
    Dim outName As String, vDict As Dictionary
    
    Dim key  As Variant, i As Long
    
    For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
    
        outName = dict.Keys(i)
        Set vDict = dict.Items(i)
        
        Debug.Print outName
        For Each key In vDict.Keys
            Debug.Print key, vDict(key)
        Next
                
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

you get the following output in the immediate window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're going to do something else with the collected data then there's no need for any intermediate data structure:

```
Dim data, r As Long, c As Long

data = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:D5").Value
For r = 2 To UBound(data, 1)
    Debug.Print data(r, 1)
    For c = 2 To UBound(data, 2)
        Debug.Print data(1, c) & " " & data(r, c)
    Next c
    Debug.Print "Checked."
Next r
```

Answer (score 0):

The location of the data should be the same as the picture to work.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, n As Long
    Dim c As Integer, j As Integer
    
    vDB = Range("a3").CurrentRegion
    
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)
    
    For i = 3 To r
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
        vR(n) = vDB(i, 1)
        For j = 2 To c
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
            If vDB(i, j) = "" Then
                vR(n) = "Checked"
            Else
                vR(n) = vDB(2, j) & Space(1) & vDB(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1").Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```

[image]

### Result Sheet

[image]